# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I get this exception when i run the code
i have again tried but i m getting it continuously
problem is student could not give test as one person is giving it this time
synchronization type of error is coming

....:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

My code:

public synchronized StudentAnswer saveAnswer(User user, String assignmentid, String answerid, String answer) throws Exception {

```
    if (user == null || user.getStudent() == null)
        throw new GeneralSecurityException("Permission Denied");

    Auditor auditor = new Auditor(user);

    AssignmentStatus status = getAssignmentStatus(user, assignmentid);
    StudentAnswer studentAnswer = getStudentAnswer(user, assignmentid, answerid);

    Object oldStatus = auditor.clone(status, new AssignmentStatus());
    //Object oldAnswer = auditor.clone(studentAnswer, new StudentAnswer());
    Object oldAnswer = auditor.clone((studentAnswer == null) ? new StudentAnswer() : studentAnswer, new StudentAnswer());
    Date now = new Date();

    if (status != null && status.isCompleted())
        return studentAnswer;

    if (studentAnswer == null) {

        Assignment assignment   = getAssignment(user, assignmentid);
        AnswerKey answerKey     = (AnswerKey) genericDao.get(AnswerKey.class, answerid);

        if (answerKey == null)
            throw new Exception("There was an error trying to save an answer.");

        if (status == null)
            status = startAssignment(user, assignment, now);

        if (status == null)
            throw new Exception("There was an error trying to start the assignment.");

        studentAnswer = new StudentAnswer();
        studentAnswer.setStudent(user.getStudent());
        studentAnswer.setCreateTime(now);
        studentAnswer.setAssignmentStatus( status );
        studentAnswer.setAssignment(assignment);
        studentAnswer.setAnswerKey( answerKey );
        studentAnswer.setQuestionNumber( answerKey.getNumber() );
        studentAnswer.setAnswerKeyCopy( answerKey.getAnswer() );

        //Adding a new answer changes your progress percentage, so we recalculate it
        updateProgress(status, now, answer);

    }
    //changing existing answer
    else {
        Long practiceId = studentAnswer.getAnswerKey().getPractice().getObjectid();

        PracticeStatus practiceStatus = null;
        for (PracticeStatus tmpPracticeStatus : (List<PracticeStatus>) status.getPracticeStatuses()) {
            if (tmpPracticeStatus.getCustomPractice().getPractice().getObjectid().longValue() == practiceId.longValue()) {
                practiceStatus = tmpPracticeStatus;
            }
        }

        //completed practice due to time out or submit?  Don't change the
        //answer.
        if (practiceStatus != null && practiceStatus.isCompleted()) {
            throw new Exception("Time is up for this practice, so answers may no longer be changed.");
            //return studentAnswer;
        }

    }

    if (answer!=null && answer.length() > 0)
        studentAnswer.setAnswer(answer.charAt(0));
    else
        studentAnswer.setAnswer(' ');

    studentAnswer.setUpdateTime(now);


    studentAnswer = (StudentAnswer) genericDao.save(studentAnswer);

    updateGrade(status);
    updateProgress(status, now, null);
    genericDao.save(status);

    auditor.audit("answer_save", status, oldStatus);
    auditor.audit("answer_save", studentAnswer, oldAnswer);
    genericDao.saveList(auditor.getList());

    return studentAnswer;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just posting your code and exception does not really help. What is your code indented to do? At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: P.S. Shouldn't there be `studentAnswer` instead of `asnwer` in your final line: `updateProgress(status, now, answer);` ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the row you are trying to update has already been updated by some other thread before your transaction is getting committed. Check whether the same record is being handled by multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is why you got this exception and how to fix it. If you system has zero tolerance to concurrent update then use pessimistic lock in your query, but you have to make sure the lock is gained in short transaction, otherwise there will be performance issue.
Or a better solution is to use optimistic lock(use version field) and check if the version equals the latest version, if not possibly send message to user say the data is out of date.